# GMail: Which email address was this listserv email addressed to?

Tags: email, gmail

I have multiple email addresses linked to my gmail account.

I am signed up to some email groups that send emails out with

```
To: all-users@some-group.com
```

I can't remember which email address I used to sign up for this group. How do I find out which email address this was addressed to?

Comment: Trial and error. Also, no, not really.

Comment: This should probably be on superuser...

Comment: Re-asked here: http://superuser.com/questions/46623/gmail-how-do-i-know-which-address-this-mailing-list-email-is-sent-to/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superuser answered this question for me:

https://superuser.com/questions/46623/gmail-how-do-i-know-which-address-this-mailing-list-email-is-sent-to

Answer (score 0):

View the message headers.  Look at the Received lines.  They should have a "for" section that specified the email address the message was intended for.

Comment: The for just has the mailing list. It doesn't say a specific email address.

Comment: There are probably multiple Received lines.  Check them all.